# What is the difference between /bin and ~/bin?

Tags: bash, directory, path

I am trying to understand exporting paths in Bash, and someone had told me that `/bin` is not the same as `~/bin`. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: One is a user directory, the other a system one...

Comment: Also look at man bash, then search for TILDE EXPANSION.

Answer (score 4):

`/bin` always refers to the "**bin**" off of the root directory **"/"**
In Bash,
`~` refers to the users home directory.
thus `~/bin` refers to bin off of the user's home directory.

If the user's home is `/users/cazs`, then `~/bin` will be `/users/cazs/bin`

`~` seems to work in the `sh` shell and its myriad of derivations, including `bash`, which is what you asked about.

Comment: It's important to note that this is a shell feature, and not always available.

Comment: Also, ~bob/bin would refer to something like /users/bob/bin.

Comment: @HackSaw, which shell doesn't support ~?

Comment: Most shells that I have used support it. Python doesn't, out of the box. You have to import os.path, and perform an explicit expansion. In general programming languages don't support it, save in libraries.

Comment: @HackSaw, thanks.  I was interpreting that some shells don't support it.  It is good to note that it is a feature of command line interface (shell), like sh, bash, zsh, csh, tcsh, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`~/bin` refers to the `bin` directory in the current user's home directory.
It is equivalent to `$HOME/bin`.
If the current user's home directory is `/home/jack`,
then `~/bin` refers to `/home/jack/bin`.

`/bin` is an absolute path, its meaning is unambiguous.